# Node.js: Read params passed in the URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

In rails I do a POST request to my server:

```
response = Typhoeus::Request.post("http://url.localtunnel.com/request?from=ola&to=ole")
result = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

In the Node.js app, I want to read `From` and `To`:

```
app.post '/request', (req,res) ->
    console.log "I have received a request, sweet!!"
    sys.log req.params.from
    #sys.log "From: " + req.from + ", To: " + req.to + ", Id: " + req.id
```

How do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

```
Checks query string params (req.query), ex: ?id=12
```

Comment: Right, `params` in Express are parsed from routes you define, e.g. `app.get('/user/:id', ...` gives you a `req.param.id`. You want `req.query`. Note that it doesn't matter here whether it's a `GET` or `POST` request.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var http = require('http'), url = require('url');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    var _url = url.parse(request.url, true);
    response.write("Hello " + _url.query["from"] + "!\n"); // etc: _url.query["to"]...
    response.close();
}).listen(8000);
```

`url.parse` is a key point... Or you can use `querystring.parse(urlString)`
You can read more at http://nodejs.org docs section.