# Fetch the value from url

Tags: node.js, url

I have to extract the access token value from the following url.

```
http://localhost:4001/app1/#access_token=FH2yCAcgmPjMOtKcp3DE&refresh_token=pjgTyaj
```

How can I fetch the full url and get the access_token value using connect in node.js?
I tried using `req.url` and `req.query` to get the full url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js: Read params passed in the URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398264/node-js-read-params-passed-in-the-url)

Comment: @vittore I already checked the above link which is related to fetch the query params. But my question is to fetch "#access_token"

Comment: It seems odd that the access_token is being passed in this way.  Is there a reason it can't be passed as a standard URL parameter?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

> The http client removes # fragments of a url before it queries the
> server for the  page, so the server never has access to it, that's
> only available to the browser.

When an agent (Browser) requests a resource from a server, the agent sends the only URI to the server (not the fragment). Instead, the agent waits for the server to send the response, then the agent processes the resource according to the document type and fragment value. [[source][1] & for more info here is a [link][2]]

So, If you are having any data in the fragment, then it is up to you to process that data (AJAX)

---

You can think to grab the hash at client JavaScript (`window.location.hash`) and send it to serve.
In case you get string like that, here is an example:

```
var req_url = 'http://localhost:4001/app1/#access_token=FH2yCAcgmPjMOtKcp3DE&refresh_token=pjgTyaj';
HashKeyValueParsed_JSON = {};
require('url').parse(req_url).hash.substring(1).split('&').forEach(function (x) {
    var arr = x.split('=');
    arr[1] && (HashKeyValueParsed_JSON[arr[0]] = arr[1]);
});
console.log(HashKeyValueParsed_JSON); //Output JSON: { access_token: 'FH2yCAcgmPjMOtKcp3DE',  refresh_token: 'pjgTyaj' }
```

You will get output:

```
{ access_token: 'FH2yCAcgmPjMOtKcp3DE',
  refresh_token: 'pjgTyaj' }
```

I recommend you to keep all your require out of loop or any functions because it a blocking call in Node.js (even though it uses cache[here is a source [link](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L355)]).
For more information you can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974436/change-node-modules-location/18974546#18974546).

Comment: req.url is giveing output /app1/. How to get the full url?

Comment: Yup, I ignored that part. My bad.. Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As per [nodejs url with hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967681/nodejs-url-with-hash), the hash portion of a url is NOT sent to the server.  You should try sending the `access_token` by query.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the url that starts with `#` is referred to as the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), or hash. Parsing the url will yield the hash.

If `req.url` returns `'http://localhost:4001/app1/#access_token=FH2yCAcgmPjMOtKcp3DE&refresh_token=pjgTyaj'`, then `require('url').parse(req.url)` returns

```
{ protocol: 'http:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'localhost:4001',
  port: '4001',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  hash: '#access_token=FH2yCAcgmPjMOtKcp3DE&refresh_token=pjgTyaj',
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/app1/',
  path: '/app1/',
  href: 'http://localhost:4001/app1/#access_token=FH2yCAcgmPjMOtKcp3DE&refresh_token=pjgTyaj' }
```

So that part you are looking for is in the `hash` property of the parsed url:
`require('url').parse(req.url).hash`

Comment: What im doing wrong here.hash value is null.<br/>router.get('/app1', function (req, res, next) {
            var fullURL = require('url').parse(req.url)
            console.log(fullURL)           
        });

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  I could create my own but it could be totally different.

Comment: router.get('/app1', function (req, res, next) {
            var req_url = require('url').parse(req.url)
            console.log(req_url); 
        });
Output
{ protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/app1/',
  path: '/app1/',
  href: '/app1/' }

Comment: How are you accessing the URL?  Through browser, wget, ...?  What is the full url being entered?

Comment: Accesing via browser using full url http://localhost:4001/app1/#access_token=FH2yCAcgmPjMOtKcp3DE&refresh_token=pjgTyaj